# How to notify a web browser from web server in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.Net MVC 3 web application in which an administrator can assign tasks to individual users. Individual users monitors some stats by looking at a dashboard page built in the same application. My requirement is, I want to notify the individual user whenever a new task is assigned to the user. Is it soemthing which can be achieved in the web application built on .net technologies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery to auto refresh.

Auto refresh a section of the page that loads from the database

[Jquery auto refresh Tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/auto-load-refresh-every-10-seconds-with.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response, sounding great but this way I need to keep checking the database at regular intervals, is there any other possibility in which I do not need to do this?

Comment: The only way you can avoid checking the database or a central repository like a text file, etc. Is to have the admin and the user in the same web site. Then use a table loaded into memory, which is not easy to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415567/using-an-ioc-container-in-mvc3-are-objects-shared-between-sessions